# What is this Patagonian biome?

Tags: botany, ecology

This image was taken in [Patagonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patagonia), near the [Torres Del Paine National Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torres_del_Paine_National_Park).

What type of biome this is? There are trees and other vegetation, but they seem mostly dried. I think this is either a semi-arid region or some type of transition zone to a forest, but I'm looking for a more concrete answer.

[image: Patagonian landscape — foreground: shrubs and a horse; background: mountains with snow and ice fields]

Comment: Certainly some kind of heathland. Looks too moist and shrubby to be [Patagonian steppe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patagonian_Desert). I'd guess a [**Magellanic subpolar forest**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magellanic_subpolar_forests) type of ecoregion. Coloration appears to be due to it being autumn. I know that there has been a long history of grazing in this region with recent efforts of conservation returning steppe to shrubbier habitats. Hard to see details on my phone. I'll try to draft up an answer when I get a chance

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! It would probably be helpful if you provided more precise location information (altitude might also be informative) — Patagonia isn't a small area and I suspect it contains multiple biomes. If you could provide identifications for any of the plants in the picture that would also be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @tyersome Unfortunately I have no information about the plants, but I did found out some more information about the photo, I'll add it.

Comment: A visual search (Bing) turned up several similarly stunning photographs at [Culture Trip](https://theculturetrip.com/south-america/argentina/articles/18-photos-that-prove-patagonia-is-the-most-amazing-place-on-earth/).  I think that the mountains are recognizable in at least one - with suspicion this photo may have been reversed.

Comment: If as @MikeSerfas has suggested this is not an image you produced it is important that you include a source and copyright information (you should not be reposting other people's work without acknowledgement and permission). Thanks!

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest any such thing - I only wanted to help understand the beautiful location.  The main thing that seems out of place about the photo above is that the animal in the foreground is not a unicorn. :)  But looking at the Wikipedia article I noticed great similarity of the mountain (not the photo!) to their lake image of Cuernos Del Paine from the Lago del Toro (but reversed), which should help to identify the biome.  Also see https://www.google.com/maps/@-51.144369,-72.6814447,14993m/data=!3m1!1e3 though it isn't as helpful as I'd hoped.

Comment: @MikeSerfas Yes, the photo was most likely reversed, already put the original, thanks!

Comment: Based on my experience, the answer to this question my further be complicated by grazing in the area. We have a horse in the image, and the ground vegetation looks like it has been grazed quite heavily (if this is a grassy type ecosystem). If this is a heathland then we seem to be missing many of the heath shrub species we would expect (Genus Ericaceae) unless they are quite small.